# RxJava and unmonitored download

Tags: android, rx-java

How would I handle this in RxJava (I am just having a fairly hard time learning this library).

I have I URL that I want to download at the start of my Android app and I want it to start even if no one is subscribing to it.  The download may take a certain amount of time so it is possible that the user could end up on the page that relies on the download of that url, so I want the Activity/Fragment to subscribe to that outstanding Observable.

I plan on tracking the outstanding Observables with a simple

```
Map<String, Observable>
```

so Observers (Activities/Fragments) can know if its url/string isn't in the map then their stuff is already done.  I was thinking of using PublishSubject, but according to a talk I heard they suggested to not use Subject's because you should learn to do it with an Observable first before you do the "shortcuts".

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this with a `PublishSubject`.

```
PublishSubject<DownloadResult> download = PublishSubject.create();
```

When your app starts, you start the download, using a classic RxJava routine with `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io)`. When the download ends, you *push* the result to the `PublishSubject`:

```
download.onNext(downloadResult);
download.onCompleted();
```

Your Activities/Fragments `Observer`s will subscribe to the `PublishSubject` and get notified when the download is completed. Piece of cake ;-)